# vsftpd folder file permission in ubuntu

Tags: permissions, apache2, vsftpd

I am using netbeans for my php project

While creating the new project I tried to create it as a "Remote project" with these settings

- **Sources Folder:** `/var/www/html/myproject`
- **Project URL:** http://ip-of-the-remote-server
- **Remote connection:** FTP details of vsftpd I created in remote server  (Test connection successful)
- **Upload directory:** `/`

Upon clicking <kbd>next</kbd> the 1st problem occurred:

It's listing all folders behind `var` like `bin`, `etc`, `var`...

Since it has check boxes I thought ok let's uncheck others, and then the second problem occurred:

When I check myproject folder alone it automatically checks `var`, `www`, and `html`

Now if proceed the local folder is been setup like

**var > www > html > myproject > var > www > html > myproject**

I checked the home directory of the ftpuser I created in vsftpd:

```
$ grep ftpuser /etc/passwd
ftpuser:x:1008:1009:PHP Server,,,:/var/www/html/myproject/:/bin/bash
```

So it seems that the home directory is wright only as `/var/www/html/myproject`

Then why does it show the folders and files above it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
Upload directory: /
```

try using

```
Upload directory: /var/www/html/myproject
```